# How to plot tif over gmap tile in R

Tags: r, plot, tiff, raster, ggmap

I want to plot a raster (.tif) over my gmap tile in R. It can be done with simple plot() function or with ggplot2 or with dismo gmap function. I found several examples, but none of them is really working for me.
Here is the simpliest way I was able to understand:

```
r<- raster(whatever.tif)
g<-gmap()
plot(g)
plot(r, add= TRUE)
```

This displays the correct gmap tile, it plots the desired raster, BUT it overlays also a huge legend over the whole visualization, making it not useful anymore.

From the question its obvious I am beginner. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix!

plot(raster(x), add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)

This will suppress your legend. If you desire to add a legend later check out ?legend.